# Electron: Scrollbar appears but it's disabled

Tags: javascript, css, electron

I have made an app with Electron.

After loading additional data via Ajax the content-list starts to become larger then the in main.js defined BrowserWindow:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 600
  });
```

Means: Not all the content becomes shown. Only a part of it. The rest below becomes hidden.

My idea is to have a scrollbars for the access the content in the list more down.
I've got currently this CSS-code:

```
html {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The scrollbars appear but they are disabled. Therefore useless.

[image]

**What do I have to do for accomplishing enabled scrollbars?**